# Motor Flux in Wb

Tags: matlab, electric-machine, simulink

I'm trying to simulate a squirrel cage motor using asynchronous machine SI units in simulink 
The problem is when I view stator Flux(both q and d) its unit is in V.s (volt second which is used for Flux linkage)but I want to view Flux of my motor -not Flux linkage-in Wb unit
Any suggestion?

Comment: 1 Wb = 1 Vs. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Well vs is used to show Flux linkage but Wb is used to show Flux. And I need Flux.

Comment: So your problem isn't about the unit but about the property you want to plot? You should clarify your question.

Comment: I will edit the question tnx for telling

Comment: Flux linkage is Wb * number of turns. Number of turns has no dimension (or unity dimension), so flux linkage and flux have the same dimension. A bit like torque and work have the same dimension Nm, you can get from one to the other by multiplying by radians (which has unity dimension).

Answer (score 0):

One Weber (Wb) *is* one Volt-second.  A Weber is the flux you get when 1 Volt of EMF in a loop is uniformly reduced to zero over one second.

The software you are using apparently shows the flux as Volt-seconds instead of Wb, but they are the same thing.  You already have what you want.